# Issue with css binding '0 1 2 3 4' instead of 'video'

Tags: knockout.js

Issue with css binding, it is deep in the app but I will try and extract the bug to fiddle unless..... (fingers crossed) you know or can guess at what's happening from the following, It seems as you can see below I've got it rendering character indexes of the class string I'm trying to add, clearly not what we want:
**THE TEMPLATE:**

```
<section data-bind="css: type" class="toolbox-tool">
<span data-bind="text: type"></span>
<label data-bind="attr: {for: id}"/>
<img data-bind="attr: {src: imageSource}"/>
</section>
```

THE RENDERED MARKUP

```
<section data-bind="css: type" class="toolbox-tool 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ui-draggable">
<span data-bind="text: type">text-ticker</span>
<label data-bind="attr: {for: id}" for="2"></label>
<img data-bind="attr: {src: imageSource}" src="#">
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout version 2.2 or higher needed.

Could have sworn I had the latest version of knockout. Oops, guess not.